# Ubuntu 13.04 not recognizing windows 8

Tags: installation, partitioning

Sorry if this has been posted before, but whenever I go to install Ubuntu it always states it is unable to find an operating system on the hard drive, if I choose "something else" I see a partition table, but I can't edit the partitions. If I choose the "Install" option it says something along the lines of "no root file system is defined".

My computer is a gateway NE56R31U with windows 8 installed.

Comment: Did you completely shut down windows? Also please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_Quickly_and_Easily_via_Trial_and_Error .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your have a machine with UEFI bootloader. That is a intel/microsoft protection plan from hackers.

Sounds like you booted into legacy from the bootloader and are trying to install from the live cd. Since the live CD would not work with UEFI in secure mode.

Before doing anything, watch the following series on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAnlhkbMang

The link is to the first one. They are three. They are high quality and put out by INTEL. It takes out a lot of the scare of the UEFI.

They aren't that long, but explains a heck of a lot. They are a step by step of installing Windows8 and Ubuntu on a newly homebuilt machine, but you can pick up with the instructions after they install windows 8. Its the same as pre-installed.

It will take you through the process of unlocking the bootloader, adding a shim, and installing ubuntu on the same machine and partitioning the hard drive. Its the whole solution that I found.

If you install right now from where your at, you will have one operating system in Legacy mode and one in Secure UEFI mode. Not the easiest setup.

As for the machine not booting in Ubuntu after install, which is mentioned down below in the comments. The following page describes what I am explaining to you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but, do I need to go into the BIOS? I tried to

Comment: If your machine has windows 8 and UEFI, and you want to dual boot. Then yes. Its not to terrible. Once your done, you will have a new view of UEFI.

Comment: What am I to do upon booting into the BIOS, enter the key /signature?

Comment: Did you watch video three? You want to boot to your usb key or live cd, then install from there. This brings up grub, and you have the option to use the live cd or install. You want to install from this point.

Comment: I did, but it really didn't seem to help, let me try again..

Comment: When you enter the BIOS, you want to set the boot manager to boot from your USB key. Or live cd. Then once it starts to boot up, you will see grub.

Comment: OK I booted into the Ubuntu Installer, but I'm still getting the same error as before when I get to the partition dialogue.

Comment: Go back into your bios, and check your boot mode. It should be in UEFI, not in Legacy mode. If you are in UEFI mode, and have that issue, you need to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_Quickly_and_Easily_via_Trial_and_Error

Comment: Ok I installed ubuntu but now its like nothing happened, I still boot into windows 8 and theres no ubuntu option in the boot manager.

Comment: Help please? I can see ubuntu has been installed on the hard drive but I cannot access it.

Comment: When you installed did you run bootrepair? And you are seeing the install from a disk partition tool in windows?

Comment: I see the disk partition when I'm in the Linux live DVD, and I see a disk in my computer which I cant open (probably that partition) I tried doing boot repair a while ago, but it said secure boot was enabled and didn't work. Also as I stated before i'm not seeing an Ubuntu option in the boot manager like the video showed.

Comment: reboot into the bios and uncheck secure boot, "disable" the function. Save your changes and let it reboot. I hope you have backup all your data! Please backup your data.

Comment: The only way I can disable secure boot is to turn off the UEFI which will launch the computer into legacy mode. If I launch the live DVD in legacy mode boot repair presents a similar error as I described before.

Comment: I edited the answer above to give you more information. I will post the same here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot . Per line 5 of ubuntu help. Given you have done steps 1 through 4. 

If the PC does not load Ubuntu (but instead loads Windows),boot your PC using the Live CD/DVD or Live USB and choose "Try Ubuntu" once again. When the live session has loaded,** run Boot-Repair. When Boot-Repair loads, click on the "Recommended repair" button, ** and write on a paper the URL  that will appear. Then reboot the pc. Please read the info from ubuntu.com on this issue.

Comment: A URL? I don't understand, as for secure boot, I told you before the only way I can get it to show up as turned off is to switch to legacy mode. There this "secure boot mode" setting but its greyed out and cant be accessed.

Comment: @guest56765, please read the linked page. You are to write down the URL boot-repair gives you. THis is for if something happens, you can post that url in the ubuntu help forum. Its something they use. Boot your pc into ubuntu from the LIVE CD or USB, like you have done before. Then follow the instructions for "BOOT-Repair". They are on the linked page with photos.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that when I get back.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166135&p=12749360#post12749360

Comment: @guest56765 Some bios require a password to be setup to unlock secureboot. All bios are different. For my acer, i had to add a password. but if your setup is like mine. After setting BIOS password it will unlock Secure Boot so that it can be enabled/disabled.

Comment: As instruction to disable "fast boot" or "hybird Boot" visit in windows 8 visit the control panel. 
Search for "change what power buttons do". Then click the link with the same name.
Now click the blue text link called ‘Change settings that are currently unavailable’. 
Then simply scroll down and under the sub-heading ‘Shutdown settings’, remove the check mark of the option called ‘Turn on fast start-up (recommended)‘. 
Then click on the ‘Save changes’ button below to close the window and apply the changes.

Comment: Ok, I successfully disabled fast boot, and I had already set a password in the BIOS but was unable to find a place to input it to unlock those features.

Comment: @guest56765 Once fast boot is unchecked. Go to shutdown in windows. Let the machince fully shutdown. Then turn the poweron. You should youtube password for UEFI. They are all different,but gateway has a video by someone.

Comment: Alright I was able to disable secure boot without going into legacy mode. Tommorow I'll see whether or not ubuntu will behave.

Comment: @guest56765 Glad to hear that. Its not about Ubuntu behaving, its the other operating system that needs to let the other be free and work in the same box.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I should have specified that better when I first wrote the comment. Anyhow, after running boot repair I was able to access the GRUB menu and boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: @guest56765 that is good news!!! Just remember what we did and once in a while. if you use windows 8, it sometimes sends out an update, which makes Ubuntu not boot. And you have to do the above again. I hope you enjoy Gnu/Linux!

Comment: Yeah, obviously I'm keeping that in mind, thanks for the help.